# Running React, Webpack on PyCharm

Tags: python, reactjs, webpack, pycharm

I want to set up a basic dev environment on Pycharm with Webpack and React. There are few plugins that have some obscure or no documentation. Any help/guidelines to set things up and make it hot-loading? I'm using a flask as the web-server.

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://github.com/alexkuz/flask-react-boilerplate

Comment: @cbll How is this related to the question?

Comment: He wants to set up a basic dev environment with webpack, react and flask. The provided link is a starting point for exactly that?